Distribute objects at one axis, having them overlapping but not intercecting with each other
I wand to distribute random objects around the pole/ one axis. My main issue right now is, that I want the objects inside a collection closer together, but also the mesh not intersecting with others.
I had the idea to assign vertex groups, with different weights, controlling the probability of how much objects get where I want them. How do i approach that?
also what do I need to do, that the objects aligning with the pole?
Origin is right where i need them, I applied scale at everything, what do I miss?


I would suggest generating a line with custom spacing according to the distance you want. Distribute Points on Faces will always give you an offset, corresponding to the width of the pole.

Possible a duplicate of How to string objects of a collection along an axis depending on their size, applying random rotation and scaling without overlapping? or How to position random instances one after another with Instance on Points based on the dimensions of the previous Instance WITHOUT OVERLAP?

This question is similar to: How to string objects of a collection along an axis depending on their size, applying random rotation and scaling without overlapping?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
